# How to change the current trace file of the oracle database process

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, database-administration

Is it possible to change the current trace file of the Oracle Database process?

Actually one of the Oracle process trace file is growing continuously and we need change the current trace file of the Oracle Database process to another so that we can remove the trace file and freeup the space.

If we remove the current trace file using os commands, the new trace file will  get generated automatically for the Oracle process ??

Should we need to restart the corresponding Oracle DB process to change the trace file??

> Operating system = Linux
>
> Database version = 12cR1

Kindly share your commands ...

Thanks,
Sasikumar

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this problem with:

```
 cat /dev/null > [trace_file_path]
```

Make sure to copy your file first